# Recursive drawing

Tags: recursion, fractals, ascii-art

I understand the basics of recursion, but when I encounter a problem like [this one](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/fractal-trees)  from hackerrank. I quickly get confused as to how to approach it.

Basically you have to draw a fractal ascii tree (made up of the letter Y), each layer going downward halves the number of Ys. I can't seem to get my head around the base step so I can generalize it to the other layers, like below:

```
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
__________________1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1___________________
___________________1___1___1___1___1___1___1___1___1___1___1___1___1___1___1___1____________________
___________________1___1___1___1___1___1___1___1___1___1___1___1___1___1___1___1____________________
____________________1_1_____1_1_____1_1_____1_1_____1_1_____1_1_____1_1_____1_1_____________________
_____________________1_______1_______1_______1_______1_______1_______1_______1______________________
_____________________1_______1_______1_______1_______1_______1_______1_______1______________________
_____________________1_______1_______1_______1_______1_______1_______1_______1______________________
______________________1_____1_________1_____1_________1_____1_________1_____1_______________________
_______________________1___1___________1___1___________1___1___________1___1________________________
________________________1_1_____________1_1_____________1_1_____________1_1_________________________
_________________________1_______________1_______________1_______________1__________________________
_________________________1_______________1_______________1_______________1__________________________
_________________________1_______________1_______________1_______________1__________________________
_________________________1_______________1_______________1_______________1__________________________
_________________________1_______________1_______________1_______________1__________________________
__________________________1_____________1_________________1_____________1___________________________
___________________________1___________1___________________1___________1____________________________
____________________________1_________1_____________________1_________1_____________________________
_____________________________1_______1_______________________1_______1______________________________
______________________________1_____1_________________________1_____1_______________________________
_______________________________1___1___________________________1___1________________________________
________________________________1_1_____________________________1_1_________________________________
_________________________________1_______________________________1__________________________________
_________________________________1_______________________________1__________________________________
_________________________________1_______________________________1__________________________________
_________________________________1_______________________________1__________________________________
_________________________________1_______________________________1__________________________________
_________________________________1_______________________________1__________________________________
_________________________________1_______________________________1__________________________________
_________________________________1_______________________________1__________________________________
_________________________________1_______________________________1__________________________________
__________________________________1_____________________________1___________________________________
___________________________________1___________________________1____________________________________
____________________________________1_________________________1_____________________________________
_____________________________________1_______________________1______________________________________
______________________________________1_____________________1_______________________________________
_______________________________________1___________________1________________________________________
________________________________________1_________________1_________________________________________
_________________________________________1_______________1__________________________________________
__________________________________________1_____________1___________________________________________
___________________________________________1___________1____________________________________________
____________________________________________1_________1_____________________________________________
_____________________________________________1_______1______________________________________________
______________________________________________1_____1_______________________________________________
_______________________________________________1___1________________________________________________
________________________________________________1_1_________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
```

If anyone could give me a push in the correct direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your picture doesn't match your description.  You can restate the problem as each subsequent line has half the number of Y characters.  Your first line will have 32 Y characters, separated by a space.  Your next line will have 16 Y characters, in between the Y characters on the first line.  You can figure out the rest.

Comment: Going upward the number of Ys doubles, but I rephrased the question since it will be generated downwards anyway.

Comment: I suppose you need to generate the exact image, can you say what size is the image: lines x cols?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, missed the update. There are 63 rows and 100 columns.

Comment: I posted an answer for you, please let me know if that helps or you need other suggestions -I already solved the problem :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the image is structured in the following way:

```
   Y01
   Y11
---------
   Y02
   Y12
---------
   Y04
   Y14
---------
   Y08
   Y18
---------
   Y016
   Y116
```

Y0x & Y1x for the letter Y: Y0x are the branches and Y1x is the trunc; x is the number if lines required to form the letter

E.g.   Y02 & Y12 - 2 lines to form the branches and 2 line to form the trunk

```
1---1
 1-1
  1
  1
```

You can notice that there is one more 'rule': when you start drawing the new letters (e.g. you go from Yx2 to Yx3) you copy the last line.

EDIT:
Let's assume you have the drawing saved in a matrix `char P[63][100]`
I would write 2 function (not the optimal approach but you can optimize it) 
- drawY - draws the Y letters according to inputs
- drawPicutre - draws the "layers" of Y

```
drawY(int startPos, int stopPos, int*line, int lvl, int count)
{
   if(lvl>=count)
   {
     P[*line][(startPos+(stopPos-startPos))/2] = '1';
     P[*line + lvl][(startPos+(stopPos-startPos))/2 +count] = '1';
     P[*line + lvl][(startPos+(stopPos-startPos))/2 -count] = '1';
     (*line)--;
     drawY(startPos,stopPos,line,lvl,count+1);
   }

}

int line=63;
drawY(0,100, &line, 16, 1); // draws the first, and largest Y
```

You just need to implement the second function, drawPicture(...) which calls drawY. You can modify drawY if you want to.

Comment: personally I'd start from the bottom an work my way up; but it's just a matter of preference.

Comment: I guess, even knowing the strucuture of the image I am having trouble breaking it out into a recursive step and a base case.

Comment: I kind of get what you are saying, except that I am unable to declare variables by the virtue of the challenge, so matrices are off the table. I am to draw the whole structure

Comment: well, you didn't say anything about variables until this point :) But it does not matter, instead of saving data in a matrix you simply print to the console. You will have to adapt the logic to the constraint the line can only increase. The basic idea is the same.

Comment: Thank you for all your help, I should be able to figure it out from here.

Comment: If you still have problems let me know.